# Is it possible to create a computed column in a Visual Studio database project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, database-project

Is it possible to create a computed column in a Visual Studio 2012 Database Project?  There is a property called 'Computed column specification -> formula' but it is greyed out and it is not possible to enter a value in it.

**Edit**
The computed column is also greyed out in VS 2013

Comment: Have you tried adding it in the "SQL" portion of the window? I know I have computed columns in my projects, but haven't tried to add them through the GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a computed column in the T-SQL pane. For example (field `FullName` below):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person] (
    [FirstName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] AS ([FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName])
);
```

Once the column is defined in T-SQL, the "Formula" option in the properties will become editable. An option for "Is Persisted" will also appear.